# Can we test gif and image with botium cli?

Tags: botium-box

I am write a test suite where in the Conversation has GIF, emoticons and images being responded by the AWS lex chatbot.

Does botium cli provide that feature to test that?

Answer (score 0):

The Botium Connector for Amazon Lex supports several response types:

- Plain text of course
- NLP information (intent + entities)
- Audio responses
- Cards

All of those can be asserted with the [included asserters](https://botium-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/05_botiumscript/index.html#using-asserters)